# Are announcements OK on Tridion Meta?

Tags: discussion

I was thinking about this yesterday as I prepared for our [Tridion 2013 Community Webinar](http://webinars.julianwraith.com/2013/02/22/march-2013-webinar/) - would it be OK to place "community announcements" in Tridion meta? It is obviously not related to this site, but it is directly related to the community.

Of course these webinars are mentioned in SDL.com or in our [community webinars site](http://webinars.julianwraith.com/) but not everyone watches those sites regularly, and I think here we would reach a bigger part of the community.

Opinions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the [featured](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag to raise announcements to your 'Community Bulletin' is fine. I would just urge vigilance to be sure "community announcement" doesn't veer into advertising and solicitation.

The subject of these 'announcements' should be widely regarded as something *community engaging*… something that will benefit community engagement as a whole. Meta posts and Community Bulletins are not simply free advertising. Consider these hypothetical examples:

- "Hey! Who's going to Super Tridion-con 7!" — ***EXCELLENT***
- "Tridion SE is having a Meetup (or contest)" — ***PERFECT***
- "Tridion Reaches 50 Million Downloads!" — ***OCCASIONAL OKAY, NOT ONGOING BULLETINS***
- "Tridion 2013 SP2 Released" — ***I WOULDN'T GO THERE***
- "ABC Development Releases LMNOP For Tridion" — ***NO***
- "Free tutorials on my blog" — ***NO***
- "Will you take our survey?" — ***NO***

Use your best judgement so we can keep this a valuable resource with the *hands-off* approach we prefer. Enjoy!

Comment: Thx Robert that clears it up a lot, although I have one question on why not the last one? You could see it as promotion which is definitely unwanted (I can understand that), on the other hand one could also see it as a valuable community announcement. Never the less I can live with what you specify.

Comment: @BartKoopman It's a slippery-slope thing. Advertising/announcements from company {X} are bad but advertising/announcements from {Y} are okay if their name is on the site? See the problem? It's a [broken window](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/) thing and problematic enough just to draw a very clear line.

Comment: Thx @Robert I see your point and agree its probably easier to keep the separation clear. I personally also hope that all of the visitors here would know about a new release already, there are enough available channels where they are announced.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I wouldn't want to see announcements about company {Z}'s Tridion add-on. I'm assuming open source news might be okay occasionally (e.g. Open Source PowerTools now compatible with 2013)? Also like how you future-proofed the answer with `2013 SP2`.

Answer (score 4):

Announcements are ok, you see them on other sites like the cycling SE site from time to time. They are done by flagging meta questions with [featured](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) as Rob stated in his answer. Once we have our own community based moderators they'll be able to apply the tag for announcement posts.

Until that time we can probably flag a post for moderator attention to ask the SE Community team to apply the tag for us.

Answer (score 3):

I would think we are free to discuss here on any topic related to Tridion, so I would say yes. So unless we get a kick back from SE moderators, let's go for it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a featured tag that Robert C used to announce when we were lacking for public beta, could use that?  Looks like it's moderator only though.